# How to clean space from native Photos app? WM10 and Lumia 640

Tags: windows-10-mobile, photos

No photos are present on the device and option to show OneDrive photos is disabled. But the app size is still around 1GB. I cannot uninstall or move it to SD Card. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Photos app size is 1 GB? That is pretty unnatural. I guess resetting your phone is the only option now. Reboot your phone once and check if there is a change in storage, if no you need to reset!